# Question regarding displacement and volume enclosed along a fixed trajectory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, displacement

Considering the motion of a particle along a fixed trajectory in which the initial displacement(fixed) is given as $X_0,Y_0,Z_0$ and the displacement at any subsequent time is given as $x(t)=f_t(X_0)$ where the functional dependence $f_t(X_0)$ changes with time....($x$ doesn't has explicit time dependence)
From this at any time $t$ $dx=\partial_{X_0}f(X_0)dX_0$ and similarly for the other two  coordinate also..
From this can we infer that the total volume $\int dv=dxdydz$ at a time $t$ is $\Pi_i f(X_i)$(given $X_0,Y_0,Z_0$)??

Comment: I can't understand how a particle trajectory will produce a volume.

Comment: It's only the accesible volume $dv$ which depends on $X_0,Y_0,Z_0$ ......my question is can it be written like this??

Comment: How does this volume relate to the trajectory of the particle?

Comment: The volume elements at $t$ and $t_0$ are related